# Upload image to Heroku with node and get its url

Tags: node.js, image, canvas, heroku, cors

I need to download images to my Heroku server, so I can draw them on a canvas for the client. I'm using the server as a proxy with CORS enabled.

My Node server on Heroku has a GET request that receives a url, downloads it to `./downloads/image.jpg` and then sends the new url back, for example: `http://foo.herokuapp.com/downloads/image.jpg`. Then the cilent can use that url to draw on a canvas without tainting it.

I am aware that Heroku will frequently remove all of the uploaded images and that S3 would be better for image hosting, but I just want those images to persist only for a minute, so how could I do it?

Also, I tried accessing the image from my browser just as it uploaded at `http://foo.herokuapp.com/app/downloads.image.jpg`, but get a 404 every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is not possible on Heroku because of its [Ephemeral Filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem)

Since posting the question, I've found a solution to the problem, using proxy requests:

```
const express = require("express")
const fetch = require("node-fetch") // To pipe received image back to caller
const cors = require("cors")
const app = express()

app.use(cors()) // Enable cross-origin resource sharing

// GET request to serve as proxy for images
app.get("/proxy", (req, resposnse) => {
  const url = req.query.url
  if (url && url.length > 0) {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.body.pipe(response))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
})
```

This way, anyone who sends a request on `/proxy` with a url that leads to an image the server will pipe it back.

For example: `.../proxy?url=https://cats.com/cat.jpg"` will return an image that can be freely drawn on a `<canvas>` element.

The same applies to `<img>` tags: `<img src=".../proxy?url=https://cats.com/cat.jpg" />`